# Compatibility of ADAL with Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Customer is triyng establish the connectivity to the DWH using SSO login from databricks cluster. If we go to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector, it talks about SLQ DB github repository but this link: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java mentions that MSAL4J is the new authentication library to be used with the Microsoft identity platform, so we need confirmation if ADAL will work or we need to upgrade to MSAL4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acquire tokens for Azure SQL DB with ADAL by using the resource:

```
https://database.windows.net/
```

If you used MSAL, you'd use this scope:

```
https://database.windows.net/.default
```

The main difference between MSAL and ADAL is that ADAL uses the older "v1" endpoint of Azure AD.
You can acquire tokens for any API using either ADAL or MSAL, v2 and MSAL do not allow calling more APIs etc.
While it is generally recommended to use MSAL now, ADAL should also work fine for you.